# FB.Event.subscribe + comments.add don't work?

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to catch event when comment is sent. What am I doing wrong? I just want to update every user comment also to facebook group wall and that's why I need to catch the event.

```
<fb:comments numposts="10" ></fb:comments>
```

FB.init and event catcher:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId  : 'sensored-app-id',
      status : true, // check login status
      cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    /* All the events registered */
    FB.Event.subscribe('comments.add', function (response) {
        // do something with response
        alert("comment added");
    });



  };

  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/fi_FI/all.js';
    e.async = true;
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
</script>
```

Comment: where would I put this code if I have a  drupal site?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add `notify="true"` attribute to the `fb:comments` tag. Once you add the attribute the comments.add event begin to work.

```
<fb:comments numposts="10" notify="true"></fb:comments>
```

or, if you're using the newer html5 compliant tags:

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-num-posts="10" data-notify="true" ></div>
```

Comment: what the? how did you find this out? it's not documented.

Comment: Adding the `notify="true"` parameter didn't fix the problem for me. Anyone else still having trouble / know of a solution?

Answer (score 5):

```
FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create', function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create', function(response) {

          FB.api({
            method: 'fql.query',
            query: "SELECT post_fbid, fromid, object_id, text, time from comment WHERE  object_id in (select comments_fbid from link_stat where url ='${session.url}') order by time desc limit 1"
          },
          function(response) {
            var feed = response[0];          
            alert(feed.text)
          }
        );
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to be sure to add the `notify="true"` tag, and if that doesn't work for you, be sure you are using the latest fbComments plugin.  Try adding the `migrated="1"` tag as below, and see if this helps:

```
<fb:comments notify="true" migrated="1"></fb:comments>
```

Comment: The migrated="1" is the only thing that worked for me for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

you should note that you have to subscribe for the events **after** calling FB.init. Works for me now. However, XML Render is having a bug recently

Answer (score 0):

Strangely, if I only have a variable assignment and an ajax post in my comment.create function(response) the event doesn't fire, but if I add a JS alert statement at the bottom or a dud return statement it works?? For example:

```
FB.Event.subscribe("comment.create", function(response) {
  var postData = "page_title='.$safe_page_title.'";

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/post/post_facebook_comment.php",
    data: postData
  });

  return true;
});
```