# Where to Place FB.Event.subscribe

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

Below is the code I'm using on my site for the Facebook Like button (and  the Share button).

It works great.  I click the Like button, and boom, there's a nice notification in my Facebook account's profile page.  Facebook even auto-generates a preview image that happens to be the logo of my site.  Wonderful.  The Like counter on my site totals up correctly.

So I want to record clicks on the Like button.  According to [this](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/) page, the code `FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {});` allows you to do this.

Where exactly in the code below should I put the code `FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {});`?

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">

    <?php

    echo '<div id="fb-root"></div>';

    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({appId: 'my_fb_app_id', status: true, cookie: true,
                 xfbml: true});
      };


      (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol +
          '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
      }());



    });

    </script>";


    echo '<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script><fb:like href="" send="true" layout="button_count" width="450" show_faces="false" font="arial"></fb:like>'; 

?>
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not entirely sure if this is correct, but according to [this stack overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3060094/fb-event-subscribe-comments-add-dont-work), you place the event subscribe code after `FB.init()` and before the anonymous function call,

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId  : 'sensored-app-id',
        status : true, // check login status
        cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    /* All the events registered */
    FB.Event.subscribe('comments.add', function (response) {
        // do something with response
        alert("comment added");
    });
};

(function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/fi_FI/all.js';
    e.async = true;
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());
```

Also, if you see [this developer's code example](http://www.saschakimmel.com/2010/05/how-to-capture-clicks-on-the-facebook-like-button/), you'll see that he places the event subscribe code after the Facebook initialization code as well.

Comment: That's right: it is generally easiest to place all the event subscriptions immediately after the initializations. That way you don't miss anything.